# using plain jquery for firebase anonymous authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, promise, deferred

I am trying to understand deferred and promise. I dont want to use any library angularfire etc., before understanding the core concept. This is what i am trying to do and always getting a wrong status. Please advise.
 ........

```
 var defObj = $.Deferred();
 var fbref = new Firebase(<<firebase url>>);
 defObj.done(function() {
           console.log('Success')
          }
        );

 defObj.fail(function() {
           console.log('Fail')
          }
        );

  defObj.resolve(
          fbref.authAnonymously(function(error, authData) {
                if (error) {
                  defObj.reject();
                }
                /*
                else if (authData) {
                    defObj.resolve();
                }
                    */
   }); 
   return defObj.promise(); 
   ........
```

Pls ignore any syntax errors. Earlier I wrapped the fbref.authAnonymously call in a seperate function. In debug mode it was falling to fail but in run mode it was always going to success.
I am sure my firebase instance is not enabled for anonymous authentication.

edited : misspelt title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are now an official part of JavaScript and you can use them in the latest browsers without a library.

```
function authAnonymously() {
  // 1
  var promise = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      var ref = new Firebase(<<firebase url>>);
      ref.authAnonymously(function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error); // 2
        } else {
          resolve(authData); // 3
        }
      });
  });
}

authAnonymously()
  .then((authData) => console.log(authData)) // 4
  .catch((error) => console.error(error)); // 5
```

Here are the five steps in this example

1. Create a Promise constructor
2. If the asynchronous action is to error, mark it with the `reject()` function.
3. If the asynchronous action is to succeed, mark it with the `resolve()` function.
4. Call the `authAnonymously()` function and begin the promise chain with the `then()` function. When successful this function will fire off.
5. Continue the promise chain with the `error()` function. If the error occurs, the `catch()` function won't fire, but this `error()` function will.

Promises work well for **one time callbacks**. For Firebase, this is great for authentication methods and `once()` calls. This is not great though for repeated callbacks, like the `on()` function.

Comment: Unable to post my code due to code formatting and it is really pain. Promise.defer() seems to be obsolete and i had to convert to the Promise constructor.

Comment: Promise.defer() isn't obsolete, you can use it in Chrome today. I updated my code to use the Promise constructor.

Comment: Let me know if there's anything else needed to cover the question. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clean.

Comment: Firefox was complaining. Thanks, I accepted the answer.